# Trying to get this jQuery selector to work in FF, currently only works in IE; regarding ReportViewer 2008

Tags: jquery, html, dom, cross-browser, reportviewer2008

The ReportViewer 2008 web control emits a nasty HTML DOM structure. I'm trying to get to a certain element deep down in the HTML, and am currently only able to get my jQuery selector working in IE. I'm hoping someone could help me out with that last part!

The HTML we're talking about looks like this (simplified for example):

```
<div id="uxReportViewer">
    <iframe id="ReportFrame_uxReportViewer">
        <html>
            <frameset id="frameset">
                <frame name="docmap" id="docmap" />
                <frame name="report" id="report">
                    <html>
                        <body class="r0">
                            <div id="oReportDiv">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td id="oReportCell" /> <!-- Goal -->
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </body>
                    </html>
                </frame>
            </frameset>
        </html>
    </iframe>
    <iframe id="PrintFrame_uxReportViewer" />
</div>
```

It's the `<td id="oReportCell" />` element that I need to grab hold of.

This currently works in IE:

```
$('div#oReportDiv > table > tbody > tr > td#oReportCell',
    $('#uxReportViewer > iframe:eq(0)')
        .contents()
        .find('html')[0]
        .document
        .frames["report"]
        .document
);
```

But in FF, I can only get so far, not even into the scope I specified:

```
$('#uxReportViewer > iframe:eq(0)')
    .contents()
    .find('html')[0] // good through here
    .document;       // document is not defined
```

Instead of `.document` in FF, there is an `ownerDocument` and a `parentNode` attribute that are HTMLDocument types, but then I can't find the frames in the document.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You can replace this `'div#oReportDiv > table > tbody > tr > td#oReportCell'` with just this: `'#oReportCell'`.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Yes, thanks. I explicitly listed out the elements for testing. The issue is that I can't find the HTML document in the "report" frame in the frameset in FF, only in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beat my head against it for a while longer and found that this works in both IE8 and FF3.6:

```
$('#oReportCell', 
    $('#uxReportViewer > iframe:eq(0)')
        .contents()
        .find('html')
        .contents()
        .find('frame[name=report]')[0]
        .contentWindow // supported by modern browsers
        .document
);
```

It's not pretty, but works.

Comment: My main concern was IE. The reporting part of the site is admin-only and will be used by users who have IE. Getting it to Firefox was simply a challenge to myself. Do you have any insights into what I could change to make it Chrome friendly? I don't have it installed to test.

Comment: Are you sure that it works in FF 3.6? It doesn't work in mine: http://jsfiddle.net/REdeN/1/

Comment: I don't think it's going to work in jsfiddle because the code excerpt I provided doesn't contain any actual content. It's definitely working in my real-life application.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ok, didn't know that.  For what it's worth, HTML Tidy thinks the HTML isn't exactly valid:

```
HTML Tidy Parsing ...
line 19 column 9 - Warning: discarding unexpected <html>
line 18 column 5 - Warning: missing </iframe> before <frameset>
line 17 column 1 - Warning: missing </div> before <frameset>
line 20 column 13 - Warning: <frameset> isn't allowed in <body> elements
line 10 column 1 - Info: <body> previously mentioned
line 21 column 17 - Warning: <frame> isn't allowed in <body> elements
line 10 column 1 - Info: <body> previously mentioned
line 3 column 1 - Warning: inserting missing 'title' element
line 4 column 3 - Warning: <style> inserting "type" attribute
line 7 column 3 - Warning: <script> inserting "type" attribute
Info: Document content looks like HTML Proprietary
8 warnings, 0 errors were found!
```

Perhaps jQuery is not designed to work in this circumstance.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I explicitly listed out the elements for testing. The issue is that I can't find the HTML document in the "report" frame in the frameset in FF to even search for #oReportCell (ie.  `$('#oReportCell').length` == 0). Simply searching for that element is not enough with nested HTML documents.

Comment: In response to your edit: yup, that's what makes this fun! I think I actually found a way around it. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing in Chrome.

When using your exact HTML code, the contents of the IFRAME are just an empty HEAD and an empty BODY. I am not able to fetch the FRAMEs.

This:

```
$('#uxReportViewer iframe:first').contents().find('html')[0].innerHTML
```

will return:

```
<head></head><body></body>
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/REdeN/